# android - how to find incompatible apis with older versions

Tags: android

I have built an app with api 23/22/21 sdk with minTargetVersion = 16.

I use Android Studio

Sometimes during the development process, I saw android giving hints that a newer api is used when minTarget is 16.

I have fixed most of those but may not be all.

Now I have written lot of code and I am looking for a way to find out all usages of newer api which are not fully compatible with older versions.

I am looking for the same in layout files as well.

Is there an easy way I can find out?

Harder way is to look at every single line of code again or source files.

Comment: I would not call this a duplicate of that question since that question deals with eclipse and not android studio. I am voting to reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Android Studio you can click on `Analyze` in the toolbar at the top > Inspect code > Whole Project

after AS is finished you will have a list of lint errors you can go through